# Showing data from website in label vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Basically, I am trying to get the the "Idle" text shown in picture below to appear in a label/textbox.

[Website code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9byt.png)

The text itself will change from 'Idle' to 'Active'. I was on adding the code to the Web Browser Navigated event.

so far I have tried:

```
Try
    Dim statusText As String
    statusText = Contact.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("line1Button").GetAttribute("Value")
     statusLbl.Text = statusText
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

I have also change the 'GetAttribute' to 'Text' rather than value.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add solved to the title of your question. If someone's answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark under their answer. (That's how we know that the question has an answer that solved your problem.) See: [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new @theB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim statusText As String
statusText = Contact.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("line1Button").InnerText
statusLbl.Text = statusText
```

Return clean text between `<div>` ... `</div>`. No html tags.

Comment: Worked perfect!!
Thank you very much for your quick reply!!